# Convert date query from oracle to SQL linked server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run this query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE,
select * from Transact where tra_date between to_date('December  01, 2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
and to_date('January  21, 2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and led_code between 8000 and 9999;
```

But when I execute the above query, I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near 'December'

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your query inside `OPENQUERY` should be quoted (inside `'`). Also, where do you close said `OPENQUERY`? What we have is incomplete

Comment: Why are there two spaces after December and January?

Comment: I just did some corrections with the below script:           SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE, 'select * from Transact where tra_date between TO_DATE('December 01, 2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('January 21, 2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy') AND LED_CODE between 8000 and 9999') BUT SAME ERROR STILL REMAINS..